# Issue with namespace. Using method from wrong object

Tags: php, namespaces, fatal-error

I'm having an issue with my code below. The error I get is:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Closure::QuizApp\Routes{closure}() must be an instance of
>   QuizApp\Routes\ServerRequestInterface, instance of Slim\Http\Request
>   given in /var/www/QuizApp/Routes/AuthRoutes.php on line 8

Is this because I'm declaring a namespace at the top? I can solve it by using an alias, but I'm curious as to why it's happening in the first place.

```
<?php

namespace QuizApp\Routes;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServiceRequestInterface;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$app->get('/login', function(ServerRequestInterface $req, ResponseInterface $resp) use ($config) {

    $callback = $config['site']['domain'] . $this->router->pathFor('fb_callback');
    return $this->FBAuthServices->redirect_to_auth_page($config['facebook']['permission'],
                                                        $callback);

});
```

**Edit** After looking at my own code, I realize I don't even need the namespace. The class that was in this file, has now been moved out. Would still love an answer though, I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare these

`must be an instance of QuizApp\Routes\ServerRequestInterface`

`use \Psr\Http\Message\ServiceRequestInterface;`

It's a typo, it should be named `ServerRequestInterface` in the `use`.

Comment: My word. I feel like a right prat now. Thank you Sven. When I used the alias I copied it from the other file I had open, then `:u` to undo, hence why it worked, then failed when I removed. ha ha. /facepalm